# SMPS Constant Current Source only works with low resistance loads

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, constant-current

I'm looking for any advice that can be given to solve this issue.
I followed the design idea from here: [buck regulator to CC source](https://m.eet.com/media/1141916/53002di.pdf) and it appears to work pretty well until I started raising the load resistance. 1Ω-2Ω works great, above 2Ω the current starts to fall off.
[image]

I first thought I was running out of head room, but with a 45V input the output voltage is only reaching about 30V. I would think that the output voltage should be able to get much closer to the input voltage.

[image]

The target Vref is 0.97V for this chip, and it's doing a pretty good job of keeping that until the load resistance goes up.
[image]

Any ideas on what to check?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your feedback op-amp U1 is only going to work correctly if its input voltages are between its supply rails. That is, 0 to 12 V.

If you try to push 4.5 A into a 4 ohm load, you'll have the output voltage at 18 V , so the U1 inputs will be at about \$\frac{21}{22}(18\ V)\$ and U1 will stop working correctly.

Try using a higher voltage to power U1 (which might require choosing an op-amp that allows higher voltage power supplies if you want to build this circuit in the real world).

Comment: Alternatively, move to low side current sensing, if the application permits.

Comment: Replace the opamp too because you’ve majorly exceeded its absolute maximum ratings.

Comment: @Andyaka, A simulated op-amp usually doesn't fail just from that. But they are cheap to replace.

Comment: Trouble is I have a really good sim and have to download a new model each time this occurs.

Comment: @ThePhoton I was so focused on the differential input value, I didn't consider that the common mode of the input was above the supply rail.  Thanks!

Comment: @BrianDrummond I like that idea too.  I'll see if I can use that in my particular application.